# Order of Group with Quarternionic Type Representation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

If an irreducible complex representation of $G$ is of quarternionic type, then it must have even order, and so the group order must be even.

However, is it further true that $G$ has order divisible by 4? So $|G|$ is never equal to $2$ mod $4$?

I have checked and this is true for $|G| \leq 200$.

Comment: Finite simple nonabelian groups seem to have order divisible by 4, so any counterexample would have to be solvable, and without loss of generality have an index two normal subgroup $N$. Then if $\tau$ is an involution we can write $V=W\oplus \tau W$ as complex $N$-irreps. Not sure where to go from here for a contradiction, though if this route is viable we'd have to invoke a quaternionic structure $J$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered affirmatively on MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186876/can-groups-of-twice-odd-order-have-quaternionic-representations).